# Pandas Time Series Machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, time-series

I have a training data set that I created in Pandas that I wanted to use for a regression machine learning algorithm.

When the Pandas dataframe was created, the data is recorded on different time intervals and I needed to do an `.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')` to my pandas dataframe. This is what the dataset looked like before the `fillna`

```
2018-03-14 23:00:02.801000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN 91.1426 NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:00:02.815000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 70.0    NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:00:02.828000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.0   NaN
2018-03-14 23:00:02.842000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 63.4788
2018-03-14 23:00:06.663000-05:00    NaN NaN 162.1682    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:00:06.716000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN 29.5647 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:15:01.853000-05:00    NaN 0.002791    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:15:01.866000-05:00    81.6872 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:15:02.871000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN 90.8571 NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:15:02.884000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 70.0    NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:15:02.897000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.0   NaN
2018-03-14 23:15:02.910000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 63.4151
2018-03-14 23:15:06.563000-05:00    NaN NaN 159.4302    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:15:06.611000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN 29.4285 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:30:01.834000-05:00    NaN 0.002786    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:30:01.847000-05:00    81.8787 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:30:02.845000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN 90.3730 NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:30:02.858000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 70.0    NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:30:02.870000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.0   NaN
2018-03-14 23:30:02.883000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 63.3431
2018-03-14 23:30:06.556000-05:00    NaN NaN 168.4906    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:30:06.616000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN 29.1521 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:45:01.819000-05:00    NaN 0.002791    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:45:01.842000-05:00    82.0446 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:45:02.816000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN 90.5178 NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:45:02.829000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 70.0    NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:45:02.842000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.0   NaN
2018-03-14 23:45:02.858000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 63.2676
2018-03-14 23:45:06.535000-05:00    NaN NaN 162.7722    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-03-14 23:45:06.582000-05:00    NaN NaN NaN 28.3280 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

This is the dataset after the `fillna.' Ultimately what I am wanting is a training dataset with just one entry every 15 minutes. Would anyone know if its possible in Python to just take the first row of a 15 minute time entry and discard the remainder? If you notice in the data there is six entry's for the time 23:00 and 8 for 23:15... I have the data in a CSV format on a Github account linked below and the file is named McheLrn.csv if anyone would want to take a look at it.

The dataframe was also filtered for 15 minute time stamp's with `df[df.index.minute.isin([0,15,30,45])]` to ensure 15 minutes only

```
2018-03-14 23:00:02.801000-05:00    81.6381 0.002791    165.7452    29.6716 91.1426 70.0    100.0   63.5461
2018-03-14 23:00:02.815000-05:00    81.6381 0.002791    165.7452    29.6716 91.1426 70.0    100.0   63.5461
2018-03-14 23:00:02.828000-05:00    81.6381 0.002791    165.7452    29.6716 91.1426 70.0    100.0   63.5461
2018-03-14 23:00:02.842000-05:00    81.6381 0.002791    165.7452    29.6716 91.1426 70.0    100.0   63.4788
2018-03-14 23:00:06.663000-05:00    81.6381 0.002791    162.1682    29.6716 91.1426 70.0    100.0   63.4788
2018-03-14 23:00:06.716000-05:00    81.6381 0.002791    162.1682    29.5647 91.1426 70.0    100.0   63.4788
2018-03-14 23:15:01.853000-05:00    81.6381 0.002791    162.1682    29.5647 91.1426 70.0    100.0   63.4788
2018-03-14 23:15:01.866000-05:00    81.6872 0.002791    162.1682    29.5647 91.1426 70.0    100.0   63.4788
2018-03-14 23:15:02.871000-05:00    81.6872 0.002791    162.1682    29.5647 90.8571 70.0    100.0   63.4788
2018-03-14 23:15:02.884000-05:00    81.6872 0.002791    162.1682    29.5647 90.8571 70.0    100.0   63.4788
2018-03-14 23:15:02.897000-05:00    81.6872 0.002791    162.1682    29.5647 90.8571 70.0    100.0   63.4788
2018-03-14 23:15:02.910000-05:00    81.6872 0.002791    162.1682    29.5647 90.8571 70.0    100.0   63.4151
2018-03-14 23:15:06.563000-05:00    81.6872 0.002791    159.4302    29.5647 90.8571 70.0    100.0   63.4151
2018-03-14 23:15:06.611000-05:00    81.6872 0.002791    159.4302    29.4285 90.8571 70.0    100.0   63.4151
2018-03-14 23:30:01.834000-05:00    81.6872 0.002786    159.4302    29.4285 90.8571 70.0    100.0   63.4151
2018-03-14 23:30:01.847000-05:00    81.8787 0.002786    159.4302    29.4285 90.8571 70.0    100.0   63.4151
2018-03-14 23:30:02.845000-05:00    81.8787 0.002786    159.4302    29.4285 90.3730 70.0    100.0   63.4151
2018-03-14 23:30:02.858000-05:00    81.8787 0.002786    159.4302    29.4285 90.3730 70.0    100.0   63.4151
2018-03-14 23:30:02.870000-05:00    81.8787 0.002786    159.4302    29.4285 90.3730 70.0    100.0   63.4151
2018-03-14 23:30:02.883000-05:00    81.8787 0.002786    159.4302    29.4285 90.3730 70.0    100.0   63.3431
2018-03-14 23:30:06.556000-05:00    81.8787 0.002786    168.4906    29.4285 90.3730 70.0    100.0   63.3431
2018-03-14 23:30:06.616000-05:00    81.8787 0.002786    168.4906    29.1521 90.3730 70.0    100.0   63.3431
2018-03-14 23:45:01.819000-05:00    81.8787 0.002791    168.4906    29.1521 90.3730 70.0    100.0   63.3431
2018-03-14 23:45:01.842000-05:00    82.0446 0.002791    168.4906    29.1521 90.3730 70.0    100.0   63.3431
2018-03-14 23:45:02.816000-05:00    82.0446 0.002791    168.4906    29.1521 90.5178 70.0    100.0   63.3431
2018-03-14 23:45:02.829000-05:00    82.0446 0.002791    168.4906    29.1521 90.5178 70.0    100.0   63.3431
2018-03-14 23:45:02.842000-05:00    82.0446 0.002791    168.4906    29.1521 90.5178 70.0    100.0   63.3431
2018-03-14 23:45:02.858000-05:00    82.0446 0.002791    168.4906    29.1521 90.5178 70.0    100.0   63.2676
2018-03-14 23:45:06.535000-05:00    82.0446 0.002791    162.7722    29.1521 90.5178 70.0    100.0   63.2676
2018-03-14 23:45:06.582000-05:00    82.0446 0.002791    162.7722    28.3280 90.5178 70.0    100.0   63.2676
```

https://github.com/bbartling/Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like `groupby` `head`, will give back the first line

```
df.groupby(df[1].str[:16]).head(1)
Out[426]: 
                                  1        3         4         5        6   \
0   2018-03-14 23:00:02.815000-05:00  81.6381  0.002791  165.7452  29.6716   
5   2018-03-14 23:15:01.853000-05:00  81.6381  0.002791  162.1682  29.5647   
13  2018-03-14 23:30:01.834000-05:00  81.6872  0.002786  159.4302  29.4285   
21  2018-03-14 23:45:01.819000-05:00  81.8787  0.002791  168.4906  29.1521   
         7     8      9        10  
0   91.1426  70.0  100.0  63.5461  
5   91.1426  70.0  100.0  63.4788  
13  90.8571  70.0  100.0  63.4151  
21  90.3730  70.0  100.0  63.3431
```